# Navigation issue HTML and CSS

Tags: css, html, navigation, navbar

I'm having some issue with my navigation bar. It turns out like this:

[image]

But I want it too look like this:

[image]

The code looks a little like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top topnav" role="navigation">
  <div class="container topnav">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="##bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand topnav" href="#" target="_blank">Name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: create a code snippet, also mention if you are using BS 3/4

Comment: Share the css properties you are using, so that we can check and provide better solution.

Comment: You need to make them `inline`, use CSS. Also provide a snippet, or at least the CSS

Comment: It appears you are using Twitter Bootstrap.  You need to tag the question as such, and be sure to clarify if you are using 3 or 4.  If you are NOT using bootstrap, then you need to include your css.

Answer (score 1):

This is a plain CSS implementation with flexbox wihtout knowing your other CSS stuff:

```css
.navbar > .container{
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between; 
}
.navbar-right{
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end; 
}
.navbar-right li{
  list-style:none;
}
.navbar a{
  display:block;
  padding:0.3em 1em 0.5em 1em;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top topnav" role="navigation">
  <div class="container topnav">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="##bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand topnav" href="#" target="_blank">Name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</nav>
```